# Different Mesh Size for Different Partitions of an Object

Tags: mesh, comsol

I am working with ComSol 5.3. I've partitioned my object into two partitions. Due to the memory issue, I prefer to set different mesh size for these two partitions. But I don't know how to do it. The following picture shows my workspace!

[image: Set Different Mesh Size for Different Partitions!]

Answer (score 1):

You have already added a "New Tetrahedral" node by right clicking and selecting it from the drop down menu.  Now add a second "New Tetrahedral" node by clicking again on the "Mesh 1" node.

Now right click on the "New Tetrahedral 1" node and select "size" from the drop down menu.  You can repeat this operation with "New Tetrahedral 2".  Select the "Size" node and in the Settings Panel you can change the parameters for the mesh.

To select different domains for each mesh, select "New Tetrahedral 1" and then click on the "Geometric Entity Level" in the Settings panel.  Change this to "domain".  Now you'll have a window which will show the domains that are part of this mesh.  If you do not change "New Tetrahedral 2", it will contain all domains you have not added to other meshes.  Image in the hyperlink below.

[How to change selected domains for mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qjbp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can add different sizes and mesh types by either right-clicking on the "Mesh" node or, I assume, from the ribbon on top of the screen. Once you add a new size and possibly new "Free Tetrahedral" node you will have an option to apply that mesh to a particular domain. Sorry for lack of specific details, I do not currently have COMSOL access. But I did use different meshes for different domains many times.